# How to operate on R data.tables from inside a function?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge DT and I want to create a function which orders it by a column variable.

The following:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(col.a = 1:5, col.b = rev(11:15), col.c = rnorm(5))
order.by.col.b <- function(my.datatable){
  my.datatable <- my.datatable[order(col.b)]
#   my.datatable <- setDT(my.datatable)[order(col.b)]
  return(my.datatable)
}
```

does appear to work:

```
order.by.col.b(my.datatable = DT)
#   col.a col.b      col.c
# 1:     5    11  0.3295078
# 2:     4    12  1.5952808
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286
# 4:     2    14  0.1836433
# 5:     1    15 -0.6264538
```

but eventually it does not change the `DT`:

```
DT
#    col.a col.b      col.c
# 1:     1    15 -0.6264538
# 2:     2    14  0.1836433
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286
# 4:     4    12  1.5952808
# 5:     5    11  0.3295078
```

It only does change the order when I assign it to the `DT`:

```
DT <- order.by.col.b(my.datatable = DT) 
DT
#    col.a col.b      col.c
# 1:     5    11  0.3295078
# 2:     4    12  1.5952808
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286
# 4:     2    14  0.1836433
# 5:     1    15 -0.6264538
```

The `DT` is huge so I want to avoid unnecessary copies.
Is `<-` the only way to go or is there a more compact/correct way to operate on data.tables from inside a function?
Moreover, I want the function `order.by.col.b` to do multiple operations on the supplied `DT`, like creating new columns, making calculations etc...

**EDIT:**

I think I got it [thanks to Arun](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html). If there is a more proper way to do it, please indicate.

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(col.a = 1:5, col.b = rev(11:15), col.c = rnorm(5))

order.by.col.b.and.create.col.d <- function(my.datatable){
  setorder(my.datatable, col.b)
  setDT(my.datatable)[, col.d := col.b + col.c]
}

DT
#    col.a col.b      col.c
# 1:     1    15 -0.6264538
# 2:     2    14  0.1836433
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286
# 4:     4    12  1.5952808
# 5:     5    11  0.3295078

order.by.col.b.and.create.col.d(my.datatable = DT)

DT
#    col.a col.b      col.c    col.d
# 1:     5    11  0.3295078 11.32951
# 2:     4    12  1.5952808 13.59528
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286 12.16437
# 4:     2    14  0.1836433 14.18364
# 5:     1    15 -0.6264538 14.37355
```

Comment: Please read the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) and help files, particularly `?setorder`, which also explains which functions modify data.tables by reference.

Comment: Thank you! If there is a more proper way to do it, please indicate.

Comment: You don't need the `setDT()` in the second line. I don't think it will hurt anything, but it is not necessary if you are feeding `order.by.col.b.and.create.col.d` a data.table object.